# How to Move an image from right to left by using style.left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following a programming course, from coursera, on week 3 chapter 12 show us how to move a image with style.left, when I run the `<script>` nothing happened and the console don't show any error, I don't know what's wrong. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>set time</title>
    <meta name="Author" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
        var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;
        function do_timer(){

            the_image = document.getElementById("stones_img");
            x_position = x_position + 1;
            the_image.style.left=x_position;
            console.log(x_position);
        }
    </script>
</head>

    <body onload="the_timer=setInterval(do_timer, 50)">
        </br>
    <button onclick="clearInterval(the_timer)">Clear</button>


    </br>       </br>       </br>
    <img id="stones_img" src="http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f196/overcracker/Blog/thundercats.png"  style="position:absolute; left:10000">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for us to debug it? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: If the CSS course does indeed teach it like that, without the `px`, maybe you should look for a more error-free tutorial site. Does it also teach you to use `</br>`? If not, where did you pick that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add units to the `left` value:

`the_image.style.left = x_position + "px";`

P.S. I know this is a course project, but just be aware that this isn’t a great way to animate elements from a performance standpoint :) A better way is to use CSS animations or transitions, which won’t cause a relayout in the browser and can be hardware accelerated.

For reference:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/

Comment: from a performance point of view also caching the image element  with `the_image = the_image || document.getElementById("stones_img");` would be better

Answer (score 0):

You should add "px" to the value, and the object should have the CSS attribute `position` set to `relative` or `absolute`.

In the case the `position` attribute be `relative`, its parent object should have the 'position' attribute set to relative too.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to add the pixels!

```
the_image.style.left=x_position + "px";
```

To make it work from right to left:

```
var the_timer, x_position = 1000, the_image;
function do_timer(){
    the_image = document.getElementById("stones_img");
    x_position = x_position - 1;
    if (x_position < 0) clearInterval(the_timer); // stop once it gets to 0
    the_image.style.left=x_position + "px";;
    console.log(x_position);
}
```

and on the image update the style on the left property:

```
style="position:absolute;left:1000px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

## you need to specify the extent

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>set time</title>
    <meta name="Author" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

    <body onload="the_timer=setInterval(do_timer, 50);the_timer2=setInterval(do_timer_translate, 50)">
        </br>
    <button onclick="CLEAR()">Clear</button>


    </br>       </br>       </br>
<h3>USING POSITION LEFT</h3>

    <img id="stones_img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/thundercats/256/the-eye-of-thundera-icon.png"  style="position:absolute;" width="100">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<h3>USING CSS3 TRANSLATE</h3>
    <img id="stones_img2" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/thundercats/256/the-eye-of-thundera-icon.png"   width="100">


<script>

    
  //---------------------- USING LEFT;

        var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;
        function do_timer(){

            the_image = document.getElementById("stones_img");
            x_position = x_position + 1;
            the_image.style.left=x_position+"px";
            console.log(x_position);
        }
  
  //------------------------ USING Translate
        function do_timer_translate(){

            the_image = document.getElementById("stones_img2");
            x_position = x_position + 1;
            the_image.style['transfrom'] = "translateX("+x_position+"px)";
            the_image.style['-webkit-transform'] = "translateX("+x_position+"px)";
            the_image.style['-ms-transform'] = "translateX("+x_position+"px)";
            the_image.style['-moz-transform'] = "translateX("+x_position+"px)";
            the_image.style['-o-transform'] = "translateX("+x_position+"px)";
            console.log(x_position);
        }
  
  //------------------------STOP
  function CLEAR(){
  clearInterval(the_timer);clearInterval(the_timer2)
  };
  

  
  

</script>

</body>
</html>
```